# (Multivariate) normality assumption for dependent variable

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, normality-assumption, dependent-variable

In their book on multilevel analysis Hox et al. (2017) write in chapter 13:
'The main assumptions are [...] (multivariate) normality for dependent variables, which is the focus of the current chapter.'

They then continue about how to detect non-normality of the residuals, heteroscedasticity, etc. What they don't talk about is, why the dependent variable should be normally distributed and how this would affect the analysis (or what to do in case the DV isn't normally distributed).

So could anybody offer some insights on the matter and do I really need to transform the DV to normality? Or could I simply use a robust approach, i.e. bootstrapping, as the residuals probably won't be normally distributed either, if the DV is not?

I'd be happy to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm by no means an expert on this subject but the literature I've read so far doesn't seem to require the dependent variable to be normally distributed and instead emphasizes the distribution of the the residuals. Is it possible for you to include any more quotes from your text that might be helpful to discern why your book in particular does mention this assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact there is an assumption of normality for the residuals, *not* for the marginal distribution of the dependent variable, as mentioned already in another answer.

Now having an assumption in statistics in general means that the method is based on some theory that requires the model assumption to hold. The theory will give distributions for statistics of interest, i.e., behind tests and confidence intervals, and potentially optimality of the method in some sense.

If the model assumption doesn't hold, it means that reality is different from what is assumed in the theory. This is actually always the case (nothing in reality is perfectly normally distributed, or independent for that matter). Actually it does *not* mean that a method will do something bad or misleading. We have a *positive* result if the model assumptions hold, but we normally don't have *negative* results if the model assumptions do not hold.

Saying that the model assumptions have to be fulfilled is misleading, as in reality this is never the case, and nothing could be done. What is important is that the model assumptions are not violated *in a way that will mislead the interpretation of the results*. So it is important to know *what kind of deviations from the model assumptions* are dangerous.

Extreme outliers will affect the effect estimation, and even more the estimation of the standard error, so they will often decrease the power of tests and increase the size of confidence intervals substantially. Strong skewness of the residual distribution is a problem as we normally want to estimate a center of a distribution, and under skewness it is ambiguous what the center is. The mean may not be the most efficient way to summarise such a distribution (note that in principle also regression estimates a mean, namely a conditional mean for every combination of explanatory variables). Problems get worse if in different places residual distributions have different degrees of skewness. Mild skewness at the same level at all places is rather harmless.

Further possible issues exist with dependence of observations and potentially  heteroscedasticity. The former is more serious, the latter may be harmless but isn't always, and sometimes it is a hint that the model can be improved or transformations are helpful.

> Do I really need to transform the DV to normality?

As normality of the DV is not needed, see above, the answer is no. However you might wonder whether you should transform in case the *residuals* are not normal. A problem here is that standard methods do not only assume normality, *they also assume that they are run on the raw data without having manipulated them in allow for nicer analyses*.

This means that *if you transform the data based on not looking normal enough* (or on not being significant or whatever, including removing outliers), *this in itself will violate the model assumptions!* (I have called this "misspecification paradox", see [this paper (to appear in Journal of Data Science, Statistics, and Visualisation)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.02218)).

So there are good reasons to *not* change the data too easily (or to do it before looking at the data on the basis of subject matter knowledge). Ultimately I'd say that model diagnostics are fine, because transforming the data or switching to nonparametric methods may do less harm than running an analysis with critical violations of its assumptions, but there is a trade-off really, and I recommend transforming the data and other data dependent actions only if it is crystal clear that these will help because model assumptions are strongly and critically violated.

Outlier are best dealt with using robust methods by the way.

You could run bootstrap if you want to have more valid (but not 100% valid) inference also in the non-normal case, however note that bootstrap is not necessarily robust in the sense that outliers may affect the bootstrap, and they actually also affect the estimator based on which you will do inference, be it classical or bootstrap. The bootstrap itself may require robustification.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to refers to the *conditional* distribution of dependent variable, not to the marginal dependent variable, which would (more or less) correspond to the entirety of the $y$ data.

Especially in these explicitly parametric models that make an assumption about, say, normality, there is an entire distribution being predicted, along with each point prediction. You’re predicting the expected value of some distribution that conditions on the features taking certain values. In this situation, you are assuming that conditional distribution to be normal, rather than the marginal distribution of the dependent variable.

This is quite consistent with the text emphasizing checking of residuals, which estimate the additive error term typically considered for Gaussian conditional distributions in regressions.

Comment: I am afraid there is no such a term of "conditional/marginal dependent variable". Perhaps you meant the "conditional/marginal distribution" of the (unique) dependent variable.